# I have JSON stringify data like this :

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
{
  "id": "3",
  "type1_id": "2",
  "type2_id": "2",
  "type3_id": "1",
  "number": "10003",
  "number2": "6454646",
  "consumer_name": null,
  "consumer_number": null,
  "consumer_father_name": null,
  "division_code": "468451",
  "consumer_account_id": null,
  "address": "Subhas Nagar bhopal",
  "date_time": "2018-10-24 16:36:49",
  "latitude": "77.4343394",
  "longitude": "23.2508008"
},
{
  "id": "4",
  "type1_id": "2",
  "type2_id": "2",
  "type3_id": "2",
  "number": "10004",
  "number2": "9956670",
  "consumer_name": null,
  "consumer_number": null,
  "consumer_father_name": null,
  "division_code": "462345",
  "consumer_account_id": null,
  "address": "Rajendra Nagar bhopal",
  "date_time": "2018-10-24 17:10:40",
  "latitude": "77.42396009999993",
  "longitude": "23.2774624"
},
{
  "id": "5",
  "type1_id": "4",
  "type2_id": "6",
  "type3_id": null,
  "number": "10005",
  "number2": "5058280",
  "consumer_name": null,
  "consumer_number": null,
  "consumer_father_name": null,
  "division_code": "462323",
  "consumer_account_id": null,
  "address": "Shivaji Nagar bhopal",
  "date_time": "2018-10-24 17:30:00",
  "latitude": "77.42335490000005",
  "longitude": "23.228385"
},
{
  "id": "6",
  "type1_id": "4",
  "type2_id": "6",
  "type3_id": null,
  "number": "10006",
  "number2": "5687456",
  "consumer_name": null,
  "consumer_number": null,
  "consumer_father_name": null,
  "division_code": "456654",
  "consumer_account_id": null,
  "address": "Hamidia Road bhopal",
  "date_time": "2018-10-31 11:43:25",
  "latitude": null,
  "longitude": null
},
```

how would i get latitude and longitude and this is my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  showmap2();
});    


function showmap2()
{

    $.post("https://colonymaintenance.com/55/mpeb/php_ajx/getlanglong.php",
    {
        showmap: ""
    },
    function(data, status){
      var stringify = JSON.stringify(data);

       document.write(stringify);
        for (var i = 0; i < stringify.length; i++) {
            console.log(stringify[i]['latitude']);
        }

    }, "json");    
}
```

i am beginer plz help me out

Comment: why to access latitude from stringified string... instead do `console.log(data[i]['latitude']);`

Comment: i want to get only latitude and longitude from json string, any Idea help me.. thanks

Comment: as I said and now you have an answer also for the same... do a for loop on "data" and not on "stringify" and everything would work fine...

Comment: If you data is JSON format just access it. If it string use `JSON.parse` first (not `stringify`...)

Comment: if confusion, please post the edited question with error if any using "data" in for loop

Comment: Also it seems like the json you provided is a bunch of objects without array bracket encapsulating... I think there is a typo... Please confirm

Comment: yes! binariedMe

Answer (score 0):

You can use that data directly after parsing it.  You don't need to call `stringify`:

```js
const data = [{
  "id": "3",
  "type1_id": "2",
  "type2_id": "2",
  "type3_id": "1",
  "number": "10003",
  "number2": "6454646",
  "consumer_name": null,
  "consumer_number": null,
  "consumer_father_name": null,
  "division_code": "468451",
  "consumer_account_id": null,
  "address": "Subhas Nagar bhopal",
  "date_time": "2018-10-24 16:36:49",
  "latitude": "77.4343394",
  "longitude": "23.2508008"
},
{
  "id": "4",
  "type1_id": "2",
  "type2_id": "2",
  "type3_id": "2",
  "number": "10004",
  "number2": "9956670",
  "consumer_name": null,
  "consumer_number": null,
  "consumer_father_name": null,
  "division_code": "462345",
  "consumer_account_id": null,
  "address": "Rajendra Nagar bhopal",
  "date_time": "2018-10-24 17:10:40",
  "latitude": "77.42396009999993",
  "longitude": "23.2774624"
},
{
  "id": "5",
  "type1_id": "4",
  "type2_id": "6",
  "type3_id": null,
  "number": "10005",
  "number2": "5058280",
  "consumer_name": null,
  "consumer_number": null,
  "consumer_father_name": null,
  "division_code": "462323",
  "consumer_account_id": null,
  "address": "Shivaji Nagar bhopal",
  "date_time": "2018-10-24 17:30:00",
  "latitude": "77.42335490000005",
  "longitude": "23.228385"
},
{
  "id": "6",
  "type1_id": "4",
  "type2_id": "6",
  "type3_id": null,
  "number": "10006",
  "number2": "5687456",
  "consumer_name": null,
  "consumer_number": null,
  "consumer_father_name": null,
  "division_code": "456654",
  "consumer_account_id": null,
  "address": "Hamidia Road bhopal",
  "date_time": "2018-10-31 11:43:25",
  "latitude": null,
  "longitude": null
}];

function logLatLon(data, status){
  data.forEach(function(d){
    console.log("lat:", d.latitude + ", lon:", d.longitude);
  })
};
    
logLatLon(data);
```

Comment: i am getting error when i tried the above one : error VM656:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.success (singlemap.php:37)
    at u (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: I edited the answer.  Try it now.  That error means JSON.parse is parsing an already parsed object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery each function like below.

```
    function showMap(){
      function(data, status){
        var stringify = JSON.parse(data);

        jQuery.each(stringify , function(index, value){
            console.log("Lat ",value.latitude + " Long ",value.longitude);
        });

      }, "json");
    }
```

Updated the answer. Try this one.

Comment: i have to use ajax not const data bcoz response comming from php page

Answer (score 0):

Please use **JSON.parse()** instead of **JSON.stringify()** --

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  showmap2();
});    


function showmap2()
{

    $.post("https://colonymaintenance.com/55/mpeb/php_ajx/getlanglong.php",
    {
        showmap: ""
    },
    function(data, status){
      var stringify = JSON.parse(data);

       document.write(stringify);
        for (var i = 0; i < stringify.length; i++) {
            console.log(stringify[i]['latitude']);
        }

    }, "json");    
}
```